# php template for different pages with different css and mysql

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, variables

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to do a PHP template system with a class, i dont like header.php footer.php or smarty or whatever blabla, just want the template.html, the class.php and page1.php, page2.php etc... with my own php code, and I've found a lot of website of people teaching how to do this but i still have lots of questions.

1) i want to add EXTRA css to some pages

2) SOME pages has php code like mysql queries and stuff like that

3) the CONTENT which would be a variable where ever i want in the template is not only words, instead is a large amount of divs and stuff, also in some pages the CONTENT variable has queries inside, like fillin a (e.g)dropdown menu.

Hope somebody can guide me in this, i actually have my tempalte for explame, (the tags are just random)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<title>CompanyName | ##TITLE##</title>

<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
##EXTRA_CSS##
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script src="DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
    <script>
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, div');
    </script>
<![endif]--> 

##EXTA_JS##

</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">  
        <div id="container_black">
            <div id="container_white">

                <div id="container_header">

                    <div id="logo_top"></div>           
                    <div id="lineas_verticales_top">
                        <div class="volver_portada"><a href="index.shtml">Volver a portada</a></div>
                        <div class="english_spanish"><u>Español</u> | <a href="../en/index.shtml" class="english_spanish">English</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav_bar_black"><div id="nav_bar_red"><div id="nav_bar_yel">

                        <ul class="menuholder"> 
                            <li class="menu_principal"><a href="#" title="Principal">Principal</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_empresa"><a href="#" title="Empresa">Empresa</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_productos"><a href="#" title="Productos">Productos</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_clientes"><a href="#" title="Clientes">Clientes</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_recetas"><a href="#" title="Recetas">Recetas</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_contacto"><a href="#" title="Contacto">Contacto</a></li> 
                        </ul> 

                    </div></div></div>
                    <div id="topbg_degr"></div>

                </div>

                <div id="container_left">
                    <div id="conmargen_left_top"></div>
                    <div id="container_conmargen_left_middle">

                        ##CONTENT##

                    </div>
                    <div id="conmargen_left_bottom"></div>

                    <!--[IF INDEX]
                    <div id="fono"></div>
                    <div id="dir"></div>
                    -->

                </div>

                <!--[IF INDEX]
                <div id="nav"></div>
                -->

                <div id="container_right">
                    <div id="conmargen_right_top"></div>
                    <div id="container_conmargen_right_middle">

                        <!--[IF PAGE OR PAGE OR PAGE]
                        <a href="#" id="recetas_poster" title="recetas"></a>
                        [ELSE IF]
                        <a href="#" id="clientes_poster" title="recetas"></a>
                        [ELSE IF]
                        <a href="#" id="productos_poster" title="recetas"></a>

                        -->

                    </div>
                    <div id="conmargen_right_bottom"></div>
                </div>

                <!--[IF INDEX]
                <div id="frame_facebook">
                <a href="#" class="facebook" title="CompanyName"><span>CompanyName</span> en Facebook</a>
                <div class="breakL"></div>
                <fb:like href="#" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="100" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
                </div>
                -->

                <br/>   

            </div> <!-- cierre del container white -->
        </div> <!-- cierre del container black -->

        <div id="footer">   
                <div class="footer_comment">
                    CompanyName Todos los derechos reservados 2011
                </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- cierre del main -->
<br/>

</body>

</html>
```

for instance contact.php, the content would be a form, and on the top of the page i have this huge php code, where i validate and all.

I'd really appreciate if somebody would put me in the right path to do this. thank you in advance.

Comment: `SOME pages has php code like mysql queries and stuff like that` - it usually called 'code smell'. Read about MVC and frameworks. Or both: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a hundred different ways you could approach this, each with their own advantages and disadvantages - using databases and/or ajax calls and/or headers and footers as you already said.  You really have to work out which way works best for your particular project or style of coding, or both.

However - if you really just want 'template.html', but have some pages with PHP, javascript, MySQL or whatever else in them - then I would suggest.

Create template.html with placeholders such as {PAGE_TITLE}, {MAIN_CONTENT} or whatever you need.

Create page1.php/page2.php etc and do any server side work, generate variables to match your placeholders.  It might be handy to store them as an array, ie:

```
PAGE_VARS array( 
                 ['TITLE'] => My Page
                 ['CONTENT'] => This is my page content
               )
```

At the end of your 'page' script, load the entire contents of template.html into a string

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.html')
```

Then, build up your template with the replaced variables using either a basic loop:

```
foreach ($PAGE_VARS as $KEY=>$VALUE) {       
   $template = str_replace("{".$KEY."}",$VALUE,$template)
}
```

(Feel free to get clever and probably more efficient with some regular expressions above, this is just a quick example.)

Output your template.

```
echo $template;
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i still have a quick doubt , where you say "this is my page content", is it ok to put a huge content? with divs and extra php?

Comment: The data passed to $PAGE_VARS should be the final content. For example, if you want to display the result of a MySQL query, first generate the query and then set the result into $PAGE_VARS['CONTENT'].

Comment: And, yes, you can have HTML in the placeholders, but not PHP. You shouldn't need any, as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a quick class (class.php) like this that will be your 'template engine' :

```
class Template {
    var $contents;

    function load($file) {
        if ($fp = fopen($file, "r")) {
            $this->contents = fread($fp, filesize($file));
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    function replace($str,$var) {
        $this->contents = str_replace("<".$str.">",$var,$this->contents);
    }

    function show() {
        $search = array(
                '/\t/', //Remove Tabs
                '/<!--[^\[-]+?-->/', //Remove Comments
                '/\n\n/' //Remove empty lines
                );
            $replace = array(
                '',
                '',
                ''
                );
        $this->contents = preg_replace($search, $replace, $this->contents);
        echo $this->contents;
    }
}
```

In your template.html file, add special tags where you want to put your content, like this :

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div id="id1"><page_title></div>
</body>
</html>
```

...

Then create a function to write inside the tags (one per zone) :

```
function writetitle($s) {
    $GLOBALS['writes']++;
    $GLOBALS['page_title'] .= $s;
    return;
}
```

finally, in your page.php, call the class, write your content, and generate the page :

```
require_once('class.php');
//Load Class
$template = new Template;
$template->load("template.html");

//Some query :
$query = mysql_query('SELECT...');
$res = mysql_num_rows($query);

//write your content :
writetitle('my title, '.$res.'');

//Generate the page :
$template->show();
```

Doing this you can create as many zones as you want. *writetitle* act like *echo*, so you can make queries and everything you want.

I hope it helps.

Comment: im really new in php, but ine the function when you say one per zone you mean:

function writetitle($s) {
    $GLOBALS['writes']++;
    $GLOBALS['page_title'] .= $s;
    $GLOBALS['extra_CSS'] .= $s;
    ...
    return;
}?? like that right?,

Answer (score 0):

Insetad of having PHP parsing your template files I would suggest writing the templates using PHP and not your own pseudo code.

It's perfectly valid to write

```
...
<body>
<?php if($fooBar == "hahahaha"):?>
  <a href="www.foobar.com">The cool foobar link</a>
<?php endif;?>
</body>
...
```

I would then create a `layout` file with all common html etc. Then using small template snippets to be inserted into the layout where the main content goes.
By having actual PHP code in your templates the PHP enginge can handle them and you don't have to write your own logic to handle loops, if statements etc.

Take a look at Zend Framework and you'll get a good idea of how you can write your template engine.